# RHEL Ruby (1.9.2) on Rails (3.0.9) and Passenger (3.0.7) Application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, ruby-on-rails-plugins, passenger

I'v been banging my head for a day with Passenger installation in order to start to serve Ruby on Rails on my RHEL server.

I have Ruby (1.9.2) on Rails (3.0.9) and Passenger (3.0.7) installed with RVM.

Apache configuration:

```
RailsBaseURI /dev/testpublic
#RackBaseURI /dev
<Directory /var/www/dev/testublic>   
        Options -MultiViews               
</Directory>
```

I generated the testproject with

```
rails new . -d mysql
rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text  
rake db:migrate
```

Then navigating to the test project i get:

> A source file that the application requires, is missing.
>
> ```
> It is possible that you didn't upload your application files
> ```
>
> correctly. Please check whether all your application files are
>   uploaded.
>       A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries
>   that this application requires.
>
> Further information about the error may have been written to the
>   application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the
>   problem.
>
> Error message:
>       no such file to load -- rubygems/path_support Exception class:
>       LoadError Application root:
>       /www/dev/rubytest

Any help or tips would be of help. Thank you!

- RR -

Comment: Got this solved. Will post howto after my newbie timer holds off :-)

Comment: You didn't have a DocumentRoot defined in your apache config.

Comment: @Douglas Yeah that too along with issues on the RVM config. I have the DocumentRoot configured in a separate file so that threw me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And to answer my own question. This is now solved.

I noticed that my installation of RVM did not complete it self as it should have. There was few read blocks and a missing profile configuration. Here is what I did to fix it:

My RVM was installed as multi-user, so that is why there were issues.

```
chmod a+rx /usr/local/rvm/ -R
chmod a+r /etc/rvmrc
```

And to /etc/profile and to my own .basch_profile

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

After this i got a different problem - now passeger was looking for the app on the wrong directory. I have my apache set so that I have all top level directories set as separate files and I can enable / disable like sites-enabled is done.

DocumetRoot on Apache configuration (httpd.conf) was set but pointing towards a subdirectory that is on a different path than where rails app was.

Document root was

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/default"
```

Where as my rails app was located in

```
/var/www/dev/testpublic
```

This resulted in passenger looking for the app on directory

```
/var/www/default/dev/testpublic
```

After modifying the confic accordingly and tweking my setup so that I could set the DocumetRoot to /var/www/ it started to work.

Hope this helps if someone else runs into similar issue.

- RR

Comment: Thanks man!  What made the difference for me was chmod a+rx /usr/local/rvm/ -R.  I found other postings where they said it was a permissions problem, but you're the only one that posted what you did to fix it.